# How to correctly bind the shared directory in the host to the docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to instantiate a docker container using **rootless** docker.

**The problem is that docker fails to correctly bind the shared directory in the host to the container. Inside the docker container:**

```
usera@dev_x86:/root$ ls -al
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

The shared directory in the host is configured as follows:

```
sudo chmod 1770 /shared
sudo chown :groupa /shared
```

, and the output of `ls -alhd /shared` shows:

```
drwxrwx--T 4 root groupa 4.0K Apr 28 06:29 /shared
```

The output of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` (in the host) for `usera` is:

```
# /etc/passwd    
usera:x:2000:2000::/home/usera:/bin/bash
# /etc/group
usera:x:2000:
groupa:x:1001:usera
```

The docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  dev_x86:
    user: 2000:2000
    hostname: dev_x86
    container_name: dev
    image: dev
    init: true
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      # used to access container via ssh
      - 20023:22
    volumes:
      - /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group:/etc/group:ro
      - /home/usera/.ssh:/root/.ssh
      - /shared:/root/shared
      - /home/usera/work_dir:/root/work_dir
        #command: /usr/sbin/sshd -D
    command: /bin/bash -l
```

The docker-compose.yml without `/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro` and `/etc/group:/etc/group:ro` also fails:

```
groups: cannot find name for group ID 2000
I have no name!@dev_x86:/root$ ls -alh
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```